# flash cs5 color scheme

Tags: flash

I usually use gedit or terminal in which I have a dark setting black bg and greenish or whitish font.

Does anyone know of a good color setting for adobe flash cs5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the look of the code text area in flash by going to:
(In Flash CS5)
preferences-->Actionscript and you can change the font, color, background color, etc.

I would suggest not using full black as your background, as it swallows up all the light.
Instead choose a very dark grey.

Then choose lighter colors. I would also suggest using high saturation colors for functions, and low saturation colors for strings.

Hope that helps.